# Button On Activity Showing Over Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment that needs to be displayed over the activity but the button in the activity keeps showing up over the fragment.I need the fragment to completely overlap the activity.

The xml of the activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/toolbarTextColor" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/toolbarTextColor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstnameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastnameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Chat" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_chat"
        android:name="user.InitiateChat_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: The incorrect Image]

```
private void init() {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_chat);
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public void showChatForm() {
    showHideFragment(fragment);
}

private void showHideFragment(final Fragment fragment) {

    final FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_from_bottom, R.anim.fragment_slide_to_bottom);

    if (fragment.isHidden()) {
        fragTransaction.show(fragment);
    } else {
        fragTransaction.hide(fragment);
    }
    fragTransaction.commit();
}
```

The init code is called on activity create.Fragment is a global variable.

Comment: send screenshot it helps us to guide better

Comment: <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Chat" /> this button is displayed over the fragment?

Comment: Please replace the layout for activity with framelayout and add the fragments as you wish with add() or replace(). The activity should only contains the container for holding the fragments.

Comment: @ZakiPathan yes i added the image

Comment: @JudeFernandes try to swap fragment and button. Fragment above Button. Just try that

Comment: in your fragment xml

Comment: post the code where u are replacing the fragment..and which button is overlapping?

Comment: in above code fragment is binded to an activity. so @JudeFernandes you have to manage this at your layout only. If you are assuming that fragment and activity are two different thing that you have implement in this code. Its not there. This is like you added to layouts to a same activity.

Comment: @AnkushBist could you provide some code that could help me achieve the same.

Comment: @ZakiPathan fragment above button did not work

Comment: what you actullay trying to achieve? mean fragment in same activity at same time or fragment on some task performing in activity?

Comment: @AnkushBist when the user clicks on the chat button a form pops up which allows him to fill in details and submit it and on submit it closes.

Comment: then its better to launch a new activity there and use startActivityForResult. this will return you the result from the activity too. Try searching for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_chat"
    android:name="user.InitiateChat_Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"   //add this
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**2nd Way**

Create a layout in your fragment and hide it's visibility during showing the fragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/toolbarTextColor" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstnameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastnameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Chat" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_chat"
        android:name="user.InitiateChat_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now in your code:

```
  private void showHideFragment(final Fragment fragment) {

    final FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_from_bottom, R.anim.fragment_slide_to_bottom);

    if (fragment.isHidden()) {
        fragTransaction.show(fragment); //show fragment
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //hide Linearlayout
    } else {
        fragTransaction.hide(fragment);
    }
    fragTransaction.commit();
}
```

Where `LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_button);`

Comment: Somehow that seemed to work , i just added the xml part and that was good to go.

Answer (score 13):

Your Button is visible because is has a default elevation of 2dp when using a Material Design Theme. You should give the layout above the button an elevation with 2 or more dp. This will make the button disappear behind the fragment layout in your case.

```
   android:elevation="2dp"
```

Comment: This is the only correct way to solve it, thank you

Comment: This was the most accurate, simple, and clear answer. This fixed my issue too! thank you!

Comment: This just solved my issue as well. Perfect response

Answer (score 0):

Try adding background color to your fragment like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#ffffff" /* Add any color you want */
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Comment: that did not work,the button still shows up over the fragment

Comment: This will not make any difference